# What is the most efficient method to search a large collection of strings for the closest match?

Tags: java, string, search, document

I have a large file (400K lines of English sentences) and need to be able to search and compare each sentence to an "input" string, which is also an English sentence. I'm not concerned of a memory footprint this application would have; I'm looking for the fastest way to do this. Currently, I have it stored as a large list of strings, and the program iterates through them all, one at a time, and compares the hamiltonian distance of each string - the one that "matches" is the one with the shortest distance. Is there something faster than this?

Comment: may be regular expression, please provide an input and output example

Comment: Have you considered [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)?

Comment: Would you be reading all the lines into memory at once? If your lines are divided into chunks by Producer thread(s) and Consumer threads process them, it might get much faster that way. Have you considered it?

Comment: I haven't considered soundex, but that sounds promising. And yes, I'll be reading all of them into memory.

Answer (score 0):

The best data structure to use here is a tree. Because in a tree, or even a search-trie (it is really written like "trie") the runtime is definitely smaller than that of a list.
You could use the java implementation of TreeSet, or write yourself an own implementation of a tree. A search-trie or a prefix tree is a search tree, where every node of the tree is a character.
A small example: 
[you can find the image of the tree at the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmVCl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmVCl.png)

In this case, if you want to find/match the word "app", you need only 3 iterations in the whole tree-data structure. This is the most efficient way I know.

Comment: 1. it's not just a trie, it's a suffix tree i.e. trie of suffixes. 2. how is TreeSet ever related to trie? 3. trie is not suitable in this case because he wants to match a single input string against lots of strings whereas trie is good in opposite situation i.e. when we have lots of input strings (patterns) to match against a few large strings